# Trying to check checkbox but in if condition it appears not to be checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to check a row(s) that i will lather update, but when i get to if condition it appears if it is not checked.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock" ItemStyle-Width="72px" HeaderStyle-Width="72px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="InStockCbx" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField> 



    protected void UsedForButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkBox = row.FindControl("InStockCbx") as CheckBox;

            if (chkBox.Checked)
            {

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());


                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE WorkTable SET InStock = 0, UsedOrder = @UsedOrder WHERE Id=@ID", conn);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 1).Value = id;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@UsedOrder", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UsedForTextBox.Text;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: Did you wrap the DataBinding of the GridView inside an `IsPostBack` check? `if (!IsPostBack) { //bind grid }`

Comment: I did not, that solved my problem. Thanks you so much!